# Highlighting a link which contains a specific word using c#

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I am extracting html from a website and is writing the output html to a word document using c#. I have completed this by using httpwerequest and by html parsing. My final step is to highlight a specific link in the word document if it contains a anchor keyword. For example I am getting several links in the html which i wrote to word like

1. Kroger recalls selections of spinach packages
2. Kroger recalls spinach over Listeria risk
3. Buy Safeway And Sell Whole Foods

These are all hyperlinks. I want to highlight those links which contain the anchor keyword named Kroger. So only the first two links will be highlighted in word document.How to achieve this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article may help to achieve what you are looking for:

[Search and highlight text in MS Word through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/220074/Search-and-Highlight-the-Text-in-Word-through-Csha)

From there, using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, you can:

1. define a range in your document specifying its start and end positions (see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.range%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for more info)
2. specify a value for the range's `HighlightColorIndex` property (e.g. a value of `wdYellow`). More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172829%28v=office.11%29.aspx) also for this one.

Comment: For that I need to access the word document again right?. I would like to do this while writing the html output to the word doc.

Comment: So if there is no option to highlight text before writing it to word, then I will go with this option. Thanks, let me check this and will get back to you.

Comment: Using this solution, you can highlight it *at the same time* as you are writing it... but not *before* I fear, yes.

Comment: Thanks, I have achieved the result.